# Why does #itself take a block?

Tags: ruby

When passing a block to `itself`, unlike `tap` and `yield_self`, it does not seem to be executed, so what is it used for?

```
'a'.itself { |it| raise }
```

Nothing is raised.

- Ruby 2.6

Comment: Have a look - https://karolgalanciak.com/blog/2017/12/26/the-aesthetics-of-ruby-kernel-number-itself-method/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can pass a block to any ruby method and it's silently ignored if not used:

```
1.to_s{ raise "1"}
# => "1"
1.to_f{ raise "1"}
# => 1.0
1.nil?{ raise "1"}
#=> false
```

Comment: Never knew that, how confusing.

Comment: It's extra confusing when used with for example openstruct. `OpenStruct.new(foo: 'bar').each { |k, v| puts "#{k} = #{v}" }` does nothing, because `.each` returns nil, the correct method is `each_pair`. Took a while to realize what was wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it's also confusing when you call `find` with a block on AR relation thinking it's an array.